# Buffers (Circle) in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have to extend the normal GeoJSON format to add some unsopported polygon like Circle.

```
{
 "type": "Circle",
 "radius" : 0.001,
 "coordinates": [
        5.417075157165527,
       43.29129488122568
 ]
}
```

This is an Example. Coordinates marks the center of circle and radius the radius (in meters).

Searching on PostGis Docs and Stackoverflow, to draw a Circle you have to user ST_BUFFER.

So Im using:

```
ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(<center of circle>),0.001, 'quad_segs=16')
```

Has you know, this draw a Circle only in 0,0 (near Africa). Other locations add a distortion that change the shape in an oval.

Im using 4326.

I have tried to search (even here) but I can't Find a solution to simply draw a circle avoid projection or transforming it.

The only post here is: [How to create a circle in meters in postgis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869980/how-to-create-a-circle-in-meters-in-postgis)
but its very old and that solution doesn't works.

Comment: why does https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MinimumBoundingCircle.html not work in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isn't it just doing what is supposed to be done? Which is to compensate the distortion due to projecting the ellipsoid into a 2D flat structure? I believe, the further away you get from the equator, the more *oval buffers* you will see.

**Examples:**

```
db=# SELECT ST_AsText(
     ST_Buffer(
        ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(43.29 5.41)'),0.001, 'quad_segs=16')
    );
```

This query returns a circle at the south-east of Ethiopia:

```
POLYGON((43.291 5.41,43.2909951847267
5.40990198285967,43.2909807852804 5.40980490967798,43.2909569403357 5.40970971532275,43.2909238795325 5.40961731656764,43.2908819212644 5.40952860326317,43.2908314696123 5.40944442976698,43.2907730104534 5.40936560671584,43.2907071067812 5.40929289321881,43.2906343932842 5.40922698954664,43.290555570233 5.4091685303877,43.2904713967368 5.40911807873565,43.2903826834324 5.40907612046749,43.2902902846773 5.40904305966427,43.290195090322 5.4090192147196,43.2900980171403 5.40900481527333,43.29 5.409,43.2899019828597 5.40900481527333,43.289804909678 5.4090192147196,43.2897097153227 5.40904305966427,43.2896173165676 5.40907612046749,43.2895286032632 5.40911807873565,43.289444429767 5.4091685303877,43.2893656067158 5.40922698954664,43.2892928932188 5.40929289321881,43.2892269895466 5.40936560671584,43.2891685303877 5.40944442976698,43.2891180787356 5.40952860326317,43.2890761204675 5.40961731656764,43.2890430596643 5.40970971532275,43.2890192147196 5.40980490967798,43.2890048152733 5.40990198285967,43.289 5.41,43.2890048152733 5.41009801714033,43.2890192147196 5.41019509032202,43.2890430596643 5.41029028467725,43.2890761204675 5.41038268343237,43.2891180787356 5.41047139673683,43.2891685303877 5.41055557023302,43.2892269895466 5.41063439328416,43.2892928932188 5.41070710678119,43.2893656067158 5.41077301045336,43.289444429767 5.4108314696123,43.2895286032632 5.41088192126435,43.2896173165676 5.41092387953251,43.2897097153227 5.41095694033573,43.289804909678 5.4109807852804,43.2899019828597 5.41099518472667,43.29 5.411,43.2900980171403 5.41099518472667,43.290195090322 5.4109807852804,43.2902902846773 5.41095694033573,43.2903826834324 5.41092387953251,43.2904713967368 5.41088192126435,43.290555570233 5.4108314696123,43.2906343932842 5.41077301045336,43.2907071067812 5.41070710678119,43.2907730104534 5.41063439328416,43.2908314696123 5.41055557023302,43.2908819212644 5.41047139673683,43.2909238795325 5.41038268343237,43.2909569403357 5.41029028467725,43.2909807852804 5.41019509032202,43.2909951847267 5.41009801714033,43.291 5.41))
```

[image]

The same procedure a bit further away from the equator, in Tunisia `POINT(9.76 36.61)`:

```
POLYGON((9.761 36.61,9.76099518472667 36.6099019828597,9.7609807852804 36.609804909678,9.76095694033573 36.6097097153227,9.76092387953251 36.6096173165676,9.76088192126435 36.6095286032632,9.7608314696123 36.609444429767,9.76077301045336 36.6093656067158,9.76070710678119 36.6092928932188,9.76063439328416 36.6092269895466,9.76055557023302 36.6091685303877,9.76047139673683 36.6091180787356,9.76038268343236 36.6090761204675,9.76029028467725 36.6090430596643,9.76019509032202 36.6090192147196,9.76009801714033 36.6090048152733,9.76 36.609,9.75990198285967 36.6090048152733,9.75980490967798 36.6090192147196,9.75970971532275 36.6090430596643,9.75961731656763 36.6090761204675,9.75952860326317 36.6091180787356,9.75944442976698 36.6091685303877,9.75936560671584 36.6092269895466,9.75929289321881 36.6092928932188,9.75922698954664 36.6093656067158,9.7591685303877 36.609444429767,9.75911807873565 36.6095286032632,9.75907612046749 36.6096173165676,9.75904305966427 36.6097097153227,9.7590192147196 36.609804909678,9.75900481527333 36.6099019828597,9.759 36.61,9.75900481527333 36.6100980171403,9.7590192147196 36.610195090322,9.75904305966427 36.6102902846773,9.75907612046749 36.6103826834324,9.75911807873565 36.6104713967368,9.7591685303877 36.610555570233,9.75922698954664 36.6106343932842,9.75929289321881 36.6107071067812,9.75936560671584 36.6107730104534,9.75944442976698 36.6108314696123,9.75952860326317 36.6108819212644,9.75961731656763 36.6109238795325,9.75970971532275 36.6109569403357,9.75980490967798 36.6109807852804,9.75990198285967 36.6109951847267,9.76 36.611,9.76009801714033 36.6109951847267,9.76019509032202 36.6109807852804,9.76029028467725 36.6109569403357,9.76038268343236 36.6109238795325,9.76047139673683 36.6108819212644,9.76055557023302 36.6108314696123,9.76063439328416 36.6107730104534,9.76070710678119 36.6107071067812,9.76077301045336 36.6106343932842,9.7608314696123 36.610555570233,9.76088192126435 36.6104713967368,9.76092387953251 36.6103826834324,9.76095694033573 36.6102902846773,9.7609807852804 36.610195090322,9.76099518472667 36.6100980171403,9.761 36.61))
```

[image]

And this one much further away, in the north of Norway `POINT(23.20 69.94)`:

```
POLYGON((23.201 69.94,23.2009951847267 69.9399019828597,23.2009807852804 69.939804909678,23.2009569403357 69.9397097153227,23.2009238795325 69.9396173165676,23.2008819212643 69.9395286032632,23.2008314696123 69.939444429767,23.2007730104534 69.9393656067158,23.2007071067812 69.9392928932188,23.2006343932842 69.9392269895466,23.200555570233 69.9391685303877,23.2004713967368 69.9391180787356,23.2003826834324 69.9390761204675,23.2002902846773 69.9390430596643,23.200195090322 69.9390192147196,23.2000980171403 69.9390048152733,23.2 69.939,23.1999019828597 69.9390048152733,23.199804909678 69.9390192147196,23.1997097153227 69.9390430596643,23.1996173165676 69.9390761204675,23.1995286032632 69.9391180787356,23.199444429767 69.9391685303877,23.1993656067158 69.9392269895466,23.1992928932188 69.9392928932188,23.1992269895466 69.9393656067158,23.1991685303877 69.939444429767,23.1991180787357 69.9395286032632,23.1990761204675 69.9396173165676,23.1990430596643 69.9397097153227,23.1990192147196 69.939804909678,23.1990048152733 69.9399019828597,23.199 69.94,23.1990048152733 69.9400980171403,23.1990192147196 69.940195090322,23.1990430596643 69.9402902846772,23.1990761204675 69.9403826834324,23.1991180787357 69.9404713967368,23.1991685303877 69.940555570233,23.1992269895466 69.9406343932842,23.1992928932188 69.9407071067812,23.1993656067158 69.9407730104534,23.199444429767 69.9408314696123,23.1995286032632 69.9408819212643,23.1996173165676 69.9409238795325,23.1997097153227 69.9409569403357,23.199804909678 69.9409807852804,23.1999019828597 69.9409951847267,23.2 69.941,23.2000980171403 69.9409951847267,23.200195090322 69.9409807852804,23.2002902846773 69.9409569403357,23.2003826834324 69.9409238795325,23.2004713967368 69.9408819212643,23.200555570233 69.9408314696123,23.2006343932842 69.9407730104534,23.2007071067812 69.9407071067812,23.2007730104534 69.9406343932842,23.2008314696123 69.940555570233,23.2008819212643 69.9404713967368,23.2009238795325 69.9403826834324,23.2009569403357 69.9402902846772,23.2009807852804 69.940195090322,23.2009951847267 69.9400980171403,23.201 69.94))
```

[image]

To make your buffer ignore the *distortion* caused by the projection, consider the following query (`POINT` in Italy):

```
SELECT 
  ST_Buffer(
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[11.26,44.42]}')::geography,
1000,'quad_segs=16')::geometry;
```

[image]

**Explanation**:

Calculations using [`GEOMETRY`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry.html) and [`GEOGRAPHY`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry.html) are made differently, and so are their results. `GEOGRAPHY` calculates the coordinates over an spherical surface (which can be much slower than `GEOMETRY`) and uses `meters` as unit of measurement, while `GEOMETRY` uses a planar projection and uses the SRS unit.

**Note**: The `GEOMETRY` casting in the end of the last query is necessary for the OP's use case, see comments bellow.

Comment: You got the problem. More you draw far from equator, more your circle looks like an ellipse.

Comment: I just wanted to bring it up, since I believe it's a cool feature. In case you really want to _not consider_ the projection, try to to use `geography` as datatype: `SELECT ST_AsText( ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(23.20 69.94)')::GEOGRAPHY,1000, 'quad_segs=16') );`

Comment: My geometry column is not related to specific SRID and when printing it to OpenLayer, I have to translate with ST_AsEWKT.
Now. I have another column with a GeoJSON with the center of the circle. 
I've tried this that is similar to your code: `UPDATE <table> SET geometry_column = ST_Buffer(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojson_column::TEXT),3857),1000,'quad_segs=16') WHERE id = 1234;`

Without `SetSRID` I get an ellipse. With it I get nothing on map.

Comment: Does it here do what you want? `SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(23.20 69.94)')::GEOGRAPHY,1000,'quad_segs=16'));`

Comment: Or maybe this? (you can remove the SRID) `UPDATE <table> SET geometry_column = ST_Buffer(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojson_column::TEXT),3857)::GEOGRAPHY,1000,'quad_segs=16') WHERE id = 1234;`. Consider creating a fiddle with some sample data, so that we know what you're getting :-)

Comment: I hot an error: column is of type geometry but expression is of type geography

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169685/discussion-between-jim-jones-and-retromime).

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try this it is for a zone one kilometer in diameter like. I test it and it works for me:

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(  
    ST_MakePoint(-122.325959,47.625138)::geography, 
    1000)::geometry;
```

See [here](https://www.compose.com/articles/geofile-everything-in-the-radius-with-postgis/) for better understanding.
I didn't test it but hope it will help you.

To recap a bit what **Abdullah Alger** did in the solution that you can see in the link above:

First he has a database called **stores** with latitude and longitude column no geometry column with Starbuck dataset.

Then he adds geometry with the query:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('stores', 'geom', 4326, 'POINT', 2);
```

After that update the geom column

Comment: Can I have an explanation on the downvote please? That will help me understand