# What is the difference between ST_Intersect on spherical geometries and geographies?

Tags: geospatial, postgis

I've run into a peculiar situation where I am trying to find any geospatial objects that lie (partially) in a polygon. When I apply the `ST_Intersect` function on two Geometries using the **WGS84 SRID** the intersection of a polygon and a point clearly North of the polygon returns `FALSE` as expected:

```sql
SELECT ST_Intersects(
    ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-12 0,12 0,12 50.7,-12 50.7,-12 0))', 4326), 
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(6.0 50.9)', 4326)
);
```

Now when I run this same query, but with two geographies instead of geometries the query returns `TRUE`:

```sql
SELECT ST_Intersects( 
    ST_GeogFromText('POLYGON((-12 0,12 0,12 50.7,-12 50.7,-12 0))'),
    ST_GeogFromText('POINT(6 50.9)')
);
```

I expect that the **geography version** uses **shortest great circle distance** to create the polygon, while the **geometry version** creates the polygon on a flat plane and only then projects this on the **WGS84** ellipse.

Can someone verify or debunk my suspicions?

I am running postgresql 9.6 with PostGis 2.4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operations on `geography` data type are done [over a sphere](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography). Operations on `geometry` data type are done over a plane.

The shortest line joining two points on a plane is a straight line.

The shortest line joining two points on a sphere is an arc. This arc is called the [great circle arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) and is build by intersecting the sphere with a plan going through the 2 points and the center of the earth.

Consequently, the arc going through -12;50.7N and +12;50.7N with pass through a point near 0;51.3N. This holds true for lines but also for polygon boundaries.

This [doc](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geography.html) has some interesting graphics to understand the concepts behind the `geography` type

Comment: Thanks! the examples in the link do confirm the hypothesis.

Comment: @JasperVijverberg another example for this well thought answer answer you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49984585/postgis-and-circle/49985343#49985343