# How to write id of nearby areas in PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

please help!

The database contains geodata of cities in WKB format.
In each row in columns `d1, d2, d3` (delivery companies), the values ​​are `1 or 0`. 1 means that there is delivery in this city. 0 means no.

If in the column d1 for any row there is `0` (no delivery), I need to find the nearest (by distance) zone for this company, where there is delivery and write the id of this zone in a new column d1_nearest (or update the data if the column is already created).

In the same way, for other delivery companies `d2 in d2_nearest, d3 in d3_nearest`.
If `d1 = 1` is set (this means that there is delivery in this zone), and `d1_nearest` is = `"NULL"`.

Source table:

```
|id   |name   |geom          |d1 |d2 |d3 |
|-----|-------|--------------|---|---|---|
|7499 |Rublevo|010300 ... B40|1  |0  |0  |
|7534 |Troitsk|010300 ... B40|1  |0  |0  |
|9629 |Maryino|010300 ... B40|1  |0  |0  |
|9937 |Vnukovo|010300 ... B40|1  |1  |0  |
|10724|Pihtino|010300 ... B40|1  |1  |0  |
|10996|Bobrovo|010300 ... B40|1  |1  |0  |
```

I search result like this:

```
|id   |name   |geom          |d1 |d2 |d3 |d1_nearest|d2_nearest|d3_nearest|
|-----|-------|--------------|---|---|---|----------|----------|----------|
|7499 |Rublevo|010300 ... B40|1  |0  |0  |NULL      |8248      |8248      |
|7534 |Troitsk|010300 ... B40|1  |0  |0  |NULL      |9937      |10723     |
|9629 |Maryino|010300 ... B40|1  |0  |0  |NULL      |9937      |10723     |
|9937 |Vnukovo|010300 ... B40|1  |1  |0  |NULL      |NULL      |10723     |
|10724|Pihtino|010300 ... B40|1  |1  |0  |NULL      |NULL      |10723     |
|10996|Bobrovo|010300 ... B40|1  |1  |0  |NULL      |NULL      |11022     |
```

Etc.

I did this, but for this option i need two tables. And I still did not understand how to make a cycle for the entire table and setting values ​​for each column from the delivery companies ... I am not very good at programming.

Please help with the task!

```
SELECT
t1.name As name,
t1.geom As geom,
t2.name As name,
t2.geom As geom,
ST_Distance (
ST_Transform (t1.geom :: geometry, 3857),
ST_Transform (t2.geom :: geometry, 3857)
) as dist
FROM cities11 As t1, cities10 As t2
WHERE t1.id = '7499' AND t1.id <> t2.id AND t2.d1 = '1'
ORDER BY ST_Distance (t1.geom, t2.geom)
LIMIT 1
```

Sample code from [this page](https://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor)

[Sample CSV](https://yadi.sk/d/JFtt0cV93gxbgQ)

Many Many Thx!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure about your tablenames and about geometry. But if you replace the tablename and `<distance_function(c.geom, c2.geom)>` to something giving you the distance between the cities, this might help:

```sql
UPDATE cities c
SET d1_nearest = (
    SELECT c2.id
    FROM cities c2
    WHERE c2.d1 = 1
    ORDER BY <distance_function(c.geom, c2.geom)>
    LIMIT 1
) WHERE d1 = 0;
```

For the other two columns it is analogous. Of course you need to create the new columns in advance.

Comment: Thx for response!! my knowledge does not allow me to compose a function for determining the location in the specified context. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You have something similar to ```ST_Distance ( ST_Transform (c2.geom :: geometry, 3857), ST_Transform (c.geom :: geometry, 3857) )``` in the code of your question. I do not know what it does, but you could have a try with it. No need to write your own distance function, I guess

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) conditions to make this filter? Maybe this [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) query will help you further:

```
WITH j AS (
SELECT id,
  CASE WHEN d1 = 0 THEN 
      (SELECT id FROM t t2 WHERE d1 = 1
       ORDER BY ST_Distance(t1.geom,t2.geom) ASC LIMIT 1)
    ELSE NULL
  END AS d1_nearest,
  CASE WHEN d2 = 0 THEN 
      (SELECT id FROM t t2 WHERE d2 = 1
       ORDER BY ST_Distance(t1.geom,t2.geom) ASC LIMIT 1)
    ELSE NULL
  END AS d2_nearest,
  CASE WHEN d3 = 0 THEN 
      (SELECT id FROM t t2 WHERE d3 = 1
       ORDER BY ST_Distance(t1.geom,t2.geom) ASC LIMIT 1)
    ELSE NULL
  END AS d3_nearest
FROM t t1
)
UPDATE t 
  SET d1_nearest = j.d1_nearest,d2_nearest = j.d2_nearest,d3_nearest = j.d3_nearest
FROM j WHERE t.id = j.id;
```

And here is your updated table:

```
SELECT 
  id, name, d1, d2, d3, d1_nearest AS np1, d2_nearest AS np2, d3_nearest AS np3 
FROM t ORDER BY id;    

  id   |              name              | d1 | d2 | d3 | np1  |  np2  |  np3  
-------+--------------------------------+----+----+----+------+-------+-------
  6600 | Горки                          |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  7497
  6733 | Восточный                      |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  8248
  6734 | Милицейский посёлок            |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  8248
  6752 | Захарьино                      |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  8248
  6753 | Липки                          |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  8248
  7103 | Ермолино                       |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  7104
  7104 | Видное                         |  1 |  0 |  1 |      | 10715 |      
  7122 | Тарычёво                       |  1 |  0 |  1 |      |  8248 |      
  7214 | Котельники                     |  1 |  1 |  1 |      |       |      
  7309 | Красногорск                    |  1 |  1 |  1 |      |       |      
  7368 | Люберцы                        |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  8248
  7376 | Немчиновка                     |  0 |  1 |  1 | 8248 |       |      
  7377 | Трёхгорка                      |  1 |  0 |  1 |      |  8248 |      
  7381 | Мамоново                       |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  7391
  7386 | Никонорово                     |  1 |  0 |  1 |      |  8248 |      
  7389 | Лохино                         |  1 |  0 |  1 |      |  8248 |      
  7391 | Одинцово                       |  1 |  0 |  1 |      |  8248 |      
  7496 | Щербинка                       |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  8248
  7497 | Долгопрудный                   |  1 |  0 |  1 |      |  8248 |      
  7498 | Химки                          |  1 |  1 |  1 |      |       |      
  7499 | Рублёво                        |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  8248
  7523 | Дзержинский                    |  1 |  0 |  1 |      |  8248 |      
  7524 | Королёв                        |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  8248
  7534 | Троицк                         |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  9937 | 10723
  7638 | Зеленоград                     |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  7498 |  7498
  7802 | Реутов                         |  1 |  1 |  1 |      |       |      
  8026 | Заречье                        |  0 |  1 |  1 | 8248 |       |      
  8118 | Мякинино                       |  0 |  0 |  1 | 8248 |  8248 |      
  8128 | Михалково                      |  0 |  1 |  0 | 7309 |       |  7309
  8223 | Московский                     |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  8248
  8224 | Института Полиомиелита         |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  9937 | 10723
  8245 | Лапшинка                       |  1 |  0 |  0 |      | 10724 | 10723
  8247 | Мосрентген                     |  0 |  0 |  1 | 8248 |  8248 |      
  8248 | Москва                         |  1 |  1 |  1 |      |       |      
  8506 | Новоивановское                 |  1 |  0 |  1 |      |  8248 |      
  8507 | Сетунь Малая                   |  0 |  0 |  1 | 8248 |  8248 |      
  8508 | Марфино                        |  1 |  1 |  1 |      |       |      
  8509 | Рождествено                    |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  8248
  8615 | Грибки                         |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  7497
  8730 | Коммунарка                     |  1 |  1 |  1 |      |       |      
  8731 | Газопровод                     |  1 |  1 |  1 |      |       |      
  8776 | Знамя Октября                  |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  8248
  8892 | Балашиха                       |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  8248
  9103 | Сапроново                      |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  7104
  9106 | Развилка                       |  1 |  1 |  1 |      |       |      
  9398 | Мытищи                         |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  8248
  9453 | Инновационный центр 'Сколково' |  0 |  1 |  0 | 7391 |       |  7391
  9629 | Марьино                        |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  9937 | 10723
  9680 | Дрожжино                       |  1 |  1 |  0 |      |       |  8248
  9937 | Внуково                        |  1 |  1 |  0 |      |       | 10723
 10417 | Солнцево-Парк                  |  1 |  1 |  0 |      |       | 10723
 10541 | Молоково                       |  0 |  1 |  0 | 7523 |       |  7523
 10620 | Отрадное                       |  1 |  1 |  0 |      |       |  7498
 10710 | Битца                          |  0 |  0 |  1 | 8248 |  8248 |      
 10715 | совхоза имени Ленина           |  1 |  1 |  1 |      |       |      
 10723 | Рассказовка                    |  1 |  0 |  1 |      |  8248 |      
 10724 | Пыхтино                        |  1 |  1 |  0 |      |       | 10723
 10996 | Боброво                        |  1 |  1 |  0 |      |       | 11022
 11022 | Бутово                         |  1 |  1 |  1 |      |       |      
 11205 | Саларьево                      |  1 |  0 |  1 |      |  8248 |      
 11315 | Кнутово                        |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  9937 | 10723
 11558 | Речник                         |  1 |  1 |  1 |      |       |      
 11643 | Путилково                      |  1 |  1 |  1 |      |       |      
 12229 | Виноградово                    |  1 |  0 |  0 |      |  8248 |  8248
(64 Zeilen)
```

Comment: This will definitely help me in my next task, filtering trips with Beijing ONLY

Comment: @arilwan this might be also helpful for your use case, you could create a heat map of areas with more/less "traffic": https://stackoverflow.com/a/50845811/2275388

Comment: Oh yes, I will be interested in generating a heatmap of Beijing and Porto cities. I shall studies this answer in more detail. You make my day!

Comment: @arilwan in this answer I simplified the function a bit using a BBOX instead of 4 different parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59853843/2275388