# Find neighboring polygons with maximum of 3 other polygons

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, touches

I have a case like the following picture

[image: //gbr]

Say I have 9 polygons, and want to get a polygon that is maximum neighbors with 3 other polygons such as polygons **1, 3, 7, 9 (yellow)**

I think this is done using `ST_Touches` in postgis, but I just come up with represent it in postgis code like

```
select a.poly_name, b.poly_name from tb a, tb b where ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom)
```

And say I want to output this like:

```
 poly_name      poly_name
     1               2
     1               4
     1               5
```

So how I get idea to done with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hint with `ST_Touches` is correct, however to get the amount of neighbor cells from one column related to other records in the same table you either need to run a subquery or call the table twice in the `FROM` clause.

Given the following grid on a table called `tb` ..

[image]

.. you can filter the cells with three neighbor cells or less like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tb q1
WHERE (
  SELECT count(*) FROM tb q2
  WHERE ST_Touches(q2.geom,q1.geom)) <=3;
```

[image]

If you want to also list which are the neighbor cells you might wanna first join the cells that touch in the `WHERE` clause and in a subquery or [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-with.html) count the results:

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT 
    q1.poly_name AS p1,q2.poly_name p2, 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY q1.poly_name) AS qt
  FROM tb q1, tb q2
  WHERE ST_Touches(q2.geom,q1.geom))
SELECT * FROM j
WHERE qt <= 3;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2884ad35c576b705fd67332cb7e69e82)

Further reading:

- [`Create Hexagons`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59853843/2275388) (maybe relevant for your project)
- [`Window Functions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-window.html)

Comment: big thanks for your clear explanation! cheers!