# QGIS & PostGIS (map points(lat and long with raduis on USA map)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, qgis

I installed QGIS and PostGIS.  I have 200 points that I want to display with a radius of 100 miles on a graph of the US.

I have imported my latitude and longitude in the PostGIS database. So I have three fields: [address], [lat], [lng].

1) Do I need to convert the lat and lng fields into a point or geom field? If so how? (st_buffer?)
2) What command/SQL do I use to display the points with radius?

I can query my points like so..

`SELECT * FROM postgis_test`

I just don't understand how to display all the points on a map with the radius.

Example points:

```
city        lat          lng
New York    40.7127753  -74.0059728
Los Angeles 34.0522342  -118.2436849
Chicago     41.8781136  -87.6297982
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a `geometry` or `geography` column, e.g. with [`AddGeometryColumn`](https://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html)  ..

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','postgis_test','geom',4326,'POINT',2);
```

.. and then update it with the output of [`ST_Buffer`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html)

```
UPDATE postgis_test 
SET geom = ST_Buffer(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng,lat),4326),50, 'quad_segs=8');
```

Parameters of `ST_Buffer` in detail:

- `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng,lat),4326)` : As you table had no `geometry` or `geography` column I used the function [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) to create one. The value 4326 corresponds to the SRS WGS84 - check which one suits your coordinates.
- `5` : radius of the buffer in **degrees**. If the first parameter is of type `geography` this value is interpreted as **meters**.
- `'quad_segs='` : number of segments used to approximate a quarter circle  (text from the [`documentation`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html))

After that you'll be able to import it into QGIS using the `Add PostGIS Layer` option.

#### Examples

Creating buffers with a radius of 5 degrees

```
CREATE TABLE public.postgis_test (city TEXT, lng NUMERIC, lat NUMERIC);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','postgis_test','geom',4326,'polygon',2);

INSERT INTO postgis_test 
VALUES ('New York',-74.00,40.71),
       ('Los Angeles',-118.24,34.05),
       ('Chicago',-87,41.87);

UPDATE postgis_test 
SET geom = ST_Buffer(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng,lat),4326),5, 'quad_segs=8');
```

Visualizing buffers in QGIS

[image]

If you want to display both points and buffers at the same time, you have to create an extra layer (table):

```
CREATE TABLE public.postgis_test (city TEXT, lng NUMERIC, lat NUMERIC);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','postgis_test','geom',4326,'point',2);

INSERT INTO postgis_test 
VALUES ('New York',-74.00,40.71),
       ('Los Angeles',-118.24,34.05),
       ('Chicago',-87,41.87);

UPDATE postgis_test SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng,lat),4326);

CREATE TABLE buffers AS
SELECT city, ST_Buffer(geom,5, 'quad_segs=8') 
FROM postgis_test;
```

[image]

If you prefer to work with meters just cast the geometry column to `geography` and pass the parameter in meters.

Creating buffers of 100 miles (~160934 meters)

```
CREATE TABLE public.postgis_test (city TEXT, lng NUMERIC, lat NUMERIC);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public','postgis_test','geom',4326,'point',2);

INSERT INTO postgis_test 
VALUES ('New York',-74.00,40.71),
       ('Los Angeles',-118.24,34.05),
       ('Chicago',-87,41.87);

UPDATE postgis_test SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng,lat),4326);

CREATE TABLE buffers AS
SELECT city, ST_Buffer(geom::geography,160934, 'quad_segs=8')::geometry 
FROM postgis_test;
```

[image]

Further reading:

- [`ST_SetSRID`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html)
- [`World Borders Dataset`](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php)
- [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you, but I am getting ERROR:  missing data for column "geom", when I run COPY cities FROM 'cities.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv);  (file has no headers, just city, lng, lat)

Comment: @user2012677 you have to create the geom column **after** importing the data to the table cities. If you do it before, postgres will try to match the amount of columns from the file to the table.. and it will fail :)

Comment: Success! Thank you, can you please explain what ST_Buffer(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng,lat),4326),5, 'quad_segs=8') is doing, what is the number 5

Comment: @user2012677 you might also want to take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49985371/2275388

Comment: I can't thank you enough, I learned a ton, one last questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59845293/caculate-point-50-miles-away-north-45-ne-45-sw