# How to add 2 points with distance between them (SRID = 32636)?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm using `python 3.6` and `postgres` DB

I have a table name: `test_table` with the following fields:
name (`text`), geo (`geometry`)

the `srid` of geo field is `32636`

I want to write a python function which get point X (wkt) and return point Y with distance of 10 meters between the points. i.e:

The X and Y are in `WKT` format

How can I calculate the point Y with X is the input ?

It seems that I can't use euclidean distance , because the `srid` is 32636

so how can I do it ?

Comment: could you add an example of how these points + resultset would look like?

Comment: The X and Y are in WKT format

Comment: great. can you add them to the question?

Comment: how to add them ?  the function gets X as wkt and need to calculate Y (wkt) which the distance between X and Y is 10 meters (srid=32636)

Comment: Just add the WKT of your geometry to the question. It is normally recommended to use `geography` instead of `geometry` for calculating distances in meters.

Comment: Isn't 32636 UTM zone 36? Then Euclidean distances should work just fine, unless you need crazy accuracy, in which case you probably need to consider local topography as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could cast your `geometry` to `geography` and [`ST_Project`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Project.html) it (in the azimuth you want). Doing so you can easily provide the distance in meters:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_table (name text, geo geometry(point,(32636)));
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('foo','SRID=32636;POINT(2076155.32235105 4828109.18280588)');

SELECT 
 ST_AsText(
  ST_Transform(
   ST_Project(
     ST_Transform(geo,4326)::geography,10,radians(45.0))::geometry,
   32636)
 )
FROM test_table;

                st_astext                 
------------------------------------------
 POINT(2076150.11319696 4828116.26815917)
(1 Zeile)
```

You can check the distance using [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html):

```
SELECT 
  ST_Distance(
    ST_Transform(geo,4326)::geography,
    ST_Project(ST_Transform(geo,4326)::geography,10,radians(45.0))::geometry )
FROM test_table;

st_distance 
-------------
          10
```

**NOTE**: I'm using `ST_Transform` to get from your projected SRS to a lon/lat SRS, so that we can cast it to `geography`, otherwise we'd get an error:

```
SELECT geo::geography FROM test_table;

ERROR:  Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography.
```

Further reading: [Caculate point 50 miles away (North, 45% NE, 45% SW)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59846149/2275388)