# creating wrong points values

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm working with `SRID=32636`

I have a `point = (2076155.32235105 4828109.18280588)`

I'm using this post:
[How to add 2 points with distance between them (SRID = 32636)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64012333/how-to-add-2-points-with-distance-between-them-srid-32636?noredirect=1#comment113199381_64012333)
to create 3 points with different distances.

I created the 3 points (source point + 3 different points with 15, 30, 70 meters from source point) with the following queries:

```
select st_asText(st_project('POINT(2076155.32235105 4828109.18280588)', 15, radians(30)))
```

I got: `POINT(35.322429431595 30.8173112915666)`

```
select st_asText(st_project('POINT(2076155.32235105 4828109.18280588)', 30, radians(30)))
```

I got: `POINT(35.3225078132829 30.8174284630566)`

```
select st_asText(st_project('POINT(2076155.32235105 4828109.18280588)', 70, radians(30)))
```

I got: `POINT(35.3227168320474 30.8177409201211)`

when I'm checking the distances between the source point and each other I got incorrect or strange distances:

```
select st_distance('POINT(2076155.32235105 4828109.18280588)','POINT (2076155.32235105 4828109.18280588)')
```

got: 0 (seems ok - no distance between source point to same source point)

```
select st_distance('POINT(2076155.32235105 4828109.18280588)','POINT(35.322429431595 30.8173112915666)')
```

got 5255531.84344186 (I expect to get 15)

```
select st_distance('POINT(2076155.32235105 4828109.18280588)','POINT(35.3225078132829 30.8174284630566)')
```

got 5255531.84330326 (I expect to get 30)

What is wrong ?

why the points I got don't give me the points with the distance I want from source point ?

How can I fix it ?

Comment: are the `15` and `30` values are supposed to be meters?

Comment: yes, in meters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing spatial reference systems and data types. If you take a look at this query of yours, one can notice that the points are clearly in two distinct SRS:

```
select st_distance('POINT(2076155.32235105 4828109.18280588)',
                   'POINT(35.3225078132829 30.8174284630566)')
```

In order to get the result of `ST_Distance` in meters you have to first convert the geometries to `geography` - there are other more complex ways. Since we cannot convert from a projected SRS to a lon/lat one, we need to first `ST_Transform` your coordinates to a lon/lat SRS and from there convert it to `geography`. After that all distance operations will be calculated in metres. The following query shows exactly what I am talking about:

```
WITH j (start_point,geo15,geo30,geo75) AS (
  VALUES (ST_Transform('SRID=32636;POINT(2076155.32235105 4828109.18280588)'::geometry,4326)::geography,
          ST_Project(ST_Transform('SRID=32636;POINT(2076155.32235105 4828109.18280588)'::geometry,4326)::geography, 15, radians(30)),
          ST_Project(ST_Transform('SRID=32636;POINT(2076155.32235105 4828109.18280588)'::geometry,4326)::geography, 30, radians(30)),
          ST_Project(ST_Transform('SRID=32636;POINT(2076155.32235105 4828109.18280588)'::geometry,4326)::geography, 75, radians(30)))
)
SELECT 
  ST_Distance(start_point,geo15),
  ST_Distance(start_point,geo30),
  ST_Distance(start_point,geo75)  
FROM j;

 st_distance | st_distance | st_distance 
-------------+-------------+-------------
          15 |          30 |          75
```