# Easy conversion of GEOMETRY point to latlng

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geometry, postgis

I am wanting to use a GEOMETRY point and radius value that I pull from a postgis table. It looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE waypoint (
  name          VARCHAR(30),
  location      GEOMETRY(Point, 3857),
  radius        INTEGER,
);

-- Update SRID to WGS84 (World Geodetic System 1984) - Standard for most calcluations worldwide
SELECT UpdateGEometrySRID('waypoint', 'location', 3857);

INSERT INTO
    waypoint (name, location, radius)
SELECT
    'Waypoiint 1', 'SRID=3857; POINT(-27.0 153.0)', 50;
```

So once I get the `location` and `radius` values in my javascript I wish to use it to display a  circle on a map.

```
       WPcircle = L.circleMarker(location, radius).addTo(mymap)
```

but that gives an error because location is invalid format. It is type GEOMETRY not latlng.

I want to do the equivalent of `ST_AsText(location)` in javascript. Can I?

Is there an easy (or any?) way to convert it in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a bad idea to try and handle the WKB or WKT formats on a `geometry` in Javascript.

Use the [`ST_X`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.1/ST_X.html) and [`ST_Y`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.1/ST_Y.html) functions to get the coordinates of a point in the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw a buffer (circle) on your map you should use [`ST_Buffer`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html). This should return a geometry with a circle from a given geometry and radius, so that you do not need to compute it in the client:

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(location,radius) FROM waypoint;
```

Further reading: [`Circles/Buffers in PostGIS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49985343/2275388)