# Why "circles" in PostGIS appear as "ellipsis" on map?

Tags: openlayers, postgis

I create circle geometries server side on a PostGIS database like this.

```sql
UPDATE element 
SET geo = ST_Buffer(
   ST_MakePoint(6.1043443253471, 42.3150676015829), 6, 'quad_segs=8')
WHERE id = 1;
```

I then fetch the WKT to be sent to openlayers on the client browser.

```sql
SELECT ST_AsText(geo) from element where id = 1
```

The problem is that the circle is displayed as an ellipsis on map like here

[image]

It is probably related to projection, but I don't understand how I could create this circle server side so that it appears as a real circle on map.

Can you help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is probably because the radius has been treated as degrees and longitudes get closer together away from the equator- If your coordinates are geographic I think you will need to cast the point as a geography https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html

Comment: I believe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49985343/2275388) deals with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is the projection, as a degree of longitude does not have the same ground length, in meters, as a degree of latitude.

That being said, the picture and the sample code don't not match, as the code instructs to create a 6 degrees wide buffer, which is +- 600km, and the point is in the Mediterranean sea instead of a backyard (maybe X and Y were swapped?).

To overcome this, you can pick a local CRS that preserve distances, such as UTM.

Alternatively, you can create the buffer using geography, which has a unit in meters by default, then cast back to geometry.

```sql
select ST_Buffer(
    ST_MakePoint(6.1043443253471, 42.3150676015829)::geography, 
    6, 'quad_segs=8'
  )::geometry  
WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need to use WGS84 to display on map like google... 
And concerning your query, I tried this but it output again an ellipsis geometry:   
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(46.21919859, 7.30204628)::geography, 4, 'quad_segs=8')::geometry) AS geo   
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: All good, I could make it work thanks